# eth0 Static IP Not Working Unless Something is Plugged Into It

Tags: networking, static-ip

On my Raspberry Pi 4B, I have eth0 set as a static ip address (192.168.220.1) in /etc/dhcpcd.conf

I have dnsmasq bound to eth0 at the same ip address to assign an ip address to any device that gets connected to eth0

On bootup, all this works fine as long as there's something physically connected to eth0. However if nothing is connected to eth0, then no static ip address gets assigned to eth0, and dnsmasq fails to start because the address to listen on doesn't exist. Once I plug something in after bootup, eth0 gets its static ip address as expected, but dnsmasq isn't running because it failed at boot. This seems to be a quirk in the way networking is setup on Raspbian, compared to most other linux distros and operating systems.

Is there a way to assign a static ip address to eth0 even when nothing is plugged into it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

adding nolink to the eth0 block in /etc/dhcpcd.conf solved the issue. Now the interface always gets its static IP address, regardless of link status.

Answer (score 1):

I know you already solved this, but just in case: if something more complicated must be done on network link events, one way to implement this is to write an `udev` rule with `SUBSYSTEM=="net"` and run a custom script from it.